# C#: Read Code Within Program at Line

Tags: c#, reflection

(I am aware this may seem somewhat useless)
So let's say I have a Console application named ConsoleApp1.cs with the following code:

```cs
1| Console.WriteLine("The ability for programs to reflect is revolutionary")
2| //Code to print line 1 as "Console.WriteLine("The ability for programs to reflect is revolutionary")"
```

How can I print (Console.WriteLine) a specified line of code in ConsoleApp1.cs as text?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What does this have to do with reflection?

Comment: Just put the entire string in a Console.WriteLine

Comment: `File.ReadLines("ConsoleApp1.cs").ElementAtOrDefault(0)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest you can get to, I think is:

```
Expression<Action> expr = () => Console.WriteLine("The ability for programs to reflect is revolutionary");
Console.WriteLine(expr.ToString());
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't take a line number as input (I up-voted it though). Why would I want to do this if it's useless? If I want to continue coding in the future, I want my program to notify me of the changes.

Comment: Hint: I think it has to do with accessing the project's source file then reading from it, one line at a time, and adding each line to a string array. The elements of the array can be accessed with an index number (also the line number).

Comment: No way to do this. Because in runtime, you don't have the source anymore. You have compiled code.

Comment: So is there C# code for decompiling or possibly disassembling (slightly different meaning) the code without having to use 3rd party software (other than Microsoft itself)?

Comment: Your answer is close enough. Until someone posts a complete answer to the question, your answer will be accepted.